# charged particles

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Why are charged particles influenced by magnetic fields? Is it the charicteristic charge itself that the field interracts with (positive or negative) or is there something else about the proton or electron that is inherent within it that interracts with the field.

Comment: Electrical current (moving charges) and magnetic fields are related by Maxwell's equations. Think of a coil electromagnet. Now if you use a resister instead of battery and you then move the magnet in and out of the coil you can create an AC voltage.

Comment: I asked why,  not how. Electrons make up current,  and current can be induced by magnetism... Thus electrons are influenced by magnetism as well... Why?

Comment: Please read my question above more carefully

Comment: Maxwell's equations explain the why...

Comment: The whole reason I got on this forum and asked for answers was to get answers,  not referrals.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the properties of elementary particles, and would be better suited for Physics.SE.

Comment: Sorry you're disappointed. I just know that I couldn't begin to explain Maxwell's equations in a few paragraphs. The theory is a truly elegant bit of physics.

Answer (score 1):

Charged particles like electron, if at rest, produce only electric field but if they start to move with a certain velocity then they produce a magnetic field in addition to the electric field.

Charged particles are not influenced by a external magnetic field if they are at rest.

But when they move they produce their own magnetic field and eventually, a magnetic force appears on the charge due to their interaction with the external magnetic field.